# Overloading the index operators in a Dictionary subclass

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, dictionary, data-structures

I have a situation where I for quite a while I've be reconstructing a set of data into a .NET Dictionary when a service comes up.  Lately that set of Data has gotten so large, I decided I just want to actually build the kev/value objects on demand.  So my though is, inherit from Dictionary, and overload the index operators.  There I'll check to see if the collection contains the key (and return the value), and if it doesn't, I'll create the object populate it to the collection and return it.

I try the following code (for simplicity I've just made the value of type string instead of the rather complex object I actually create):

```
  public class BroadcastDictionary<TKey, TItem> : Dictionary<TKey, TItem>
  {
     public string this[TKey key]
     {
        get
        {
           if (!base.ContainsKey(key))
           {
              try
              {
                 //Construct the object and put it
                 // into the collection:
                 string newValue = "new value!";
                 base.Add((TKey)key, (TItem)newValue);
              }
              catch
              {
                 ;// Log the lazy object generation failure
              }
           }

           if (base.ContainsKey(key))
              return base[key].ToString();
           else
              throw new Exception("BroadcastDictionary value object lazy load failure.");
        }
     }
  }
```

However, I get hung up on not being able insert the value using `Dictionary.Add(key, value)`.  Any thoughts on how I might repair and make functional this piece of code?

EDIT: The problem is that the above code does not compile.  At the `base.Add((TKey) key, (TItem)newValue);` the compiler reports error "Error   2   Cannot convert type 'string' to 'TItem'".

Comment: You better derive from IDict and store a Dict as a field. That way you control everything and don't leak implementation details.

Comment: Do you really need generic Key and Value.  If not you could just do this which an Indexer using backing Dictionary.

Comment: "get hung up on not being able to insert" how?  Does it throw an exception saying the item is already in the dictionary? If so, do you have multiple threads hitting this thing?  In that case, you may need to put a lock around the try/catch so only one thread can get there at a time.

Comment: You cannot overload the indexer when inheriting from `Dictionary`.  You can only ever hide it, meaning anyone who has one of your dictionaries can cast it to `Dictionary` and use the base class's indexer, subverting all of your code.

Comment: @dwilliss I omitted the fact that a compiler errer (Error 2 Cannot convert type 'string' to 'TItem') occurs on the line where I invoke `base.Add((TKey)key, (TItem)newValue)`.

Comment: In a real implementation, you would replace the `string newValue = "new value!";` line with something that would actually construct a TItem instead of a string.

Comment: Instead of inhering, why not create a `TryGetOrAdd` extension method?

Comment: @EtienneMaheu I'd like to keep in tact a decent sized body of code that is already centered around using the Dictionary indexer.

Comment: In that case, I would still avoid inheriting from Dictionary and would instead implement the `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` interface through composition; like @usr recommended. This way, you will avoid the problems @Servy mentioned.

Comment: @EtienneMaheu thanks, compositing is the best way for my circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

For this to work, what you pass as the value parameter for Add needs to be a TItem. Your dictionary's value type is a TItem, so that's all that you can add to it. The index method should also use the new keyword. So long as whatever TItem is has a public parameterless constructor, the code below will work for lazily creating it:

```
public class BroadcastDictionary<TKey, TItem> : Dictionary<TKey, TItem> where TItem : new()
{
    public new string this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            if (!base.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                try
                {
                    //Construct the object and put it
                    // into the collection:
                    var item = new TItem();
                    base.Add(key, item);
                }
                catch
                {
                    ;// Log the lazy object generation failure
                }
            }

            if (base.ContainsKey(key))
                return base[key].ToString();
            else
                throw new Exception("BroadcastDictionary value object lazy load failure.");
        }
    }
}
```